# Was Abiathar the son of Ahimelech or was Ahimelech the son of Abiathar?

Tags: contradiction, textual-criticism, hebrew-bible

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Was Abiathar the son of Ahimelech or was Ahimelech the son of Abiathar?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2955/was-abiathar-the-son-of-ahimelech-or-was-ahimelech-the-son-of-abiathar)

According to the following three verses, **Abiathar was the son of Ahimelech**:

1 Samuel 22:20. 
1 Samuel 23:6. 
1 Samuel 30:7.

But a couple other passages down the road claim that in fact **Ahimelech was the son of Abiathar**:

2 Samuel 8:17. 
1 Chronicles 24:6.

Which is it? Is this a contradiction?